# Encapsulate .py and .txt file into .exe file using PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

I have a 2 files that I want to put in a .exe file.
One of those files is a .py and another is a .txt
I couldn't find how to take more than one file and turn it into an executable.
Please help.

Comment: please write what you tried and why it didn't work as you expected

Comment: It gave this error even though I gave it main.py in the argument: pyinstaller: error: the following arguments are required: scriptname

Comment: the thing is you cant? you have to put that .txt file into a folder and access that file through python through that folder then you convert .py file to .exe and store it in the same directory as folder that contains that .txt file

Comment: The txt file contains text that is accessed by the py file. Is there a way to make the entire directory where both the files are stored executable?

Comment: dont think so only thing you can do as far as I know is make .py file a .exe file and this .exe file will access either the folder where .txt file is stored or directory where .exe file is stored. NOTE that either way the folder containig the file or file have to be stored in the same directory as .exe file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the .txt file in a folder and then put the name of the folder in the < folder > tags:
`pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --add-data "<folder>;<folder>" <filename.py>`

Comment: Also, what to put in the --add-data?

Comment: nothing changes of the command above, just the folder and the .py folder name:

Comment: Example: pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --add-data "textfolder;textfolder" app.py

Comment: I'm very sorry but I don't get it. Is textfolder a directory where both the py file and txt files are stored?

Comment: No look, in a directory you have your main.py file and in the same directory af folder containing only your .txt file. In the directory of the main.py file you have to enter the above command. If you still don't understand let me know ;)